# Override response of Rest authentication(HttpBearerAuth) in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-api

I have token based authorization, for which i have did below changes.

In **User** model, override `findIdentityByAccessToken()` method as below.

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
  $userlogin = Userdevices::find()->where(['access_token' => $token])->one();

  if ($userlogin == array()) {
      return null;
  } else {
      $User = Users::findOne(['id' => $userlogin->user_id]);
      if (!count($User))
      {
          return null;
      }
      else {
          $dbUser = [
              'id' => $User->id,
          ];
          return new static($dbUser);
      }
  }
}
```

In Controller, I add `behaviors()` as below.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors[] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

When API does not get token or token is not valid it gives below response

```
{
    "name": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "You are requesting with an invalid credential.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 401,
    "type": "yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"
}
```

I want to change response as per my requirement as below.

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "name": "Unauthorized",
    "is_logout": "Y",
    "status": "error",
    "message": "logout"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change format of response using `beforeSend` event of `yii\web\Response`.

For example add following methods in your api controller:

```php
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    \Yii::$app->response->on(
        \yii\web\Response::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND,
        [$this, 'beforeResponseSend']
    );
}

public function beforeResponseSend(\yii\base\Event $event)
{
    /**
     * @var \yii\web\Response $response
     */
    $response = $event->sender;
    if ($response->data['status'] == 401) {
        $response->data = [
            'code' =>  401,
            'name' => 'Unauthorized',
            'is_logout' => 'Y',
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'logout',
        ];
    }
}
```

The `init` method of controller registers the `beforeSend` event. The `beforeResponseSend` method handles the event and changes the response format.

If you want to format response in multiple controller it might be better to put the event handler into own class for example

```php
namespace app\components;

class ErrorResponseHelper
{
    public static function beforeResponseSend(Event $event)
    {
        // ... formating code ...
    }
}
```

And register the event in `config/web.php`

```php
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => [
                \app\components\ErrorResponseHelper::class,
                'beforeResponseSend',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

But be careful with this solution because this way the `\app\components\ErrorResponseHelper::beforeResponseSend` will be called during each request.

Comment: @Micheal Thanks for the answer, I tried both the way but looks it is not working

Comment: @YasinPatel I've tested the first way with new yii2 basic app and it worked fine. Maybe it's not working because of some of your configuration? The second option is just another way to register the event, i haven't tested it but the way it's registered matches the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-handling-errors#error-format) except the callback is given as class, method pair instead of closure.

Comment: It is possible that this both are for Customizing Error Response

Comment: because here it send response before calling any method as user is not  logged in

Comment: @YasinPatel When the request without proper Bearer token comes the processing should look like this (simplified): 
1. The controller is created. The init() method is called during that process unless you've overriden constructor.
2. Filters are applied. `ContentNegotiator` sets format. `HttpBearerAuth` throws exception.
3. The error handler handles the exception and prepares the content of response.
4. Right before the response is send the beforeSend event is raised.
5. The response is sent.

In my first variant the event is registered in step 1 and response is modified in step 4.

Comment: I can think about two possible reasons why it might not work. 
First option is that you've overriden constructor of controller wihtou calling its parent. So the init() method is not called and the event handler is not registered. But in that case the second option should work.

Other option is, that there is something done with `\yii\web\Response` that prevents raising event or removes the event handler registration before the event is raised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201878/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-michal-hyncica).